# How to bind specific window to a hotkey?

Tags: macos, keyboard, automator, shortcut, automation

On Windows I use a simple [Autohotkey script](https://gist.github.com/alexmorozov/48e8bf90fa85cab909c8) that allows me to easily bind to and switch beetween opened windows.

For example, I'm about to be using a browser, two consoles and a text editor in the next hour. So I open the browser and press `Ctrl+Win+1` to bind it to the `1` key. Similarly, I map consoles to `2` and `3` keys, and the editor to `4` key.

And now I can switch to the specific app just by pressing `Alt+<number>`. It allows me to work literally not touching a mouse for hours. I can't imagine my life without it.

**The question is**: How do I achieve this on El Capitan? I've tried the Automator and Karabiner apps, but did not succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Try out [Witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/) - among many other features:

```
Choose any of the first ten windows with a single keypress.
```

Comment: Does "first" mean "recently switched to"? If it does, then it wouldn't be of much help: the key-window associations will change as we cycle through the windows.